# tsql in lambda - select count group by

Tags: c#, lambda, entity

How can I do this query in Lambda and LINQ?

```
select COUNT(*) as total, int_page
        from dbo.tbl_usuarios_online
           group by int_page
               order by total desc
```

I do not want to use:

```
var lambda = ctx.tbl_usuarios_online.**SqlQuery**()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = ctx.tbl_usuarios_online.GroupBy(x => x.int_page)
                                    .Select(group => new { total = group.count(), 
                                                           int_page = group.Key })
                                    .OrderByDescending(y => y.total);
```